# How to fetch data from API in vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I want to use vuex to store some data fetched from the server that my SPA Vue app will need in different pages, this to avoid that a new ajax request is made every time that the user will change product page (it's an headless ecommerce).

My question is simple, how I can push the fetched data into an array that is defined in my store? How I will get the data in my components? I'm writing the code but not sure if I've done it well.

```js
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'

export default createStore({
  state: {
    products: []
  },
  mutations: {
    updateProductsData(state, products){
      // not sure how to proceed here
    }
  },
  actions: {
    fetchProducts(){
      const baseURL = 'https://www.example.com/app/index.php/wp-json/shop/v1/products';
      let productsData = [];
      axios.get(baseURL).then( response => {
        response.data.forEach( el => {    
          console.log(el);
          let details = {
            id: el.id,
            slug: el.slug,
            name: el.name,
            price: el.price,
            description: el.description,
            short_description: el.short_description
          }
          productsData.push(details);
        });
        store.commit('updateProductsData', productsData);
      }).catch( e => console.log(e) );
    }
  }
})
```

In my components where I need to load the data I have this code

```js
export default {
  name: 'Home',
  data(){
    return {
      loaded: false,
      offers: [],      
    }
  },
  created(){

  }, 
  mounted(){
    this.$store.dispatch('fetchProducts').then( res => this.offers.push(res) )   
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your store action to return the products data array.

```
fetchProducts() {
  const baseURL = "https://www.example.com/app/index.php/wp-json/shop/v1/products";
  const productsData = [];

  axios
    .get(baseURL)
    .then(response => {
      response.data.forEach(el => {
        console.log(el);

        const details = {
          id: el.id,
          slug: el.slug,
          name: el.name,
          price: el.price,
          description: el.description,
          short_description: el.short_description
        };

        productsData.push(details);
      });
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
    });

  return productsData;
}
```

Now when you dispatch the action from your component, the results we be sent back.

**Better Way**

A better way to do this would simply be to return the Axios call itself which is a Promise, which you can `await` on in your component.

Alternatively, you can wrap the Axios call in your own Promise and resolve it with just the data, handling errors and objects in your component for better feedback to the user, as follows:

```
fetchProducts() {
  const baseURL = "https://www.example.com/app/index.php/wp-json/shop/v1/products";

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios
      .get(baseURL)
      .then(response => {
        resolve(response.data);
      })
      .catch(e => {
        reject(e);
      });
  });
}
```

**Proper Way**

To use the store properly, you should implement your VueX action like:

```
fetchProducts({ commit }) {
  const baseURL = "https://www.example.com/app/index.php/wp-json/shop/v1/products";

  axios
    .get(baseURL)
    .then(response => {
      commit("setProductData", res.data);
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e); 
    });
  });
}
```

Add the following mutation:

```
setProductData(state, productData) {
  state.products = productData.map(product => {
    return {
      id: product.id,
      slug: product.slug,
      name: product.name,
      price: product.price,
      description: product.description,
      short_description: product.short_description
    };
  });
}
```

Update your component to be:

```
export default {
  name: "Home",
  data() {
    return {
      loaded: false,
      offers: []
    };
  },
  computed: {
    products() {
      return this.$store.state.products;
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch("fetchProducts");
  }
};
```

To get by ID, add a computed property like:

```
findProductById(id) {
  return this.products.find(product => product.id === id);
}
```

Comment: I've followed your suggestion and all seems working fine. The only problem I have is that I need to get single products from the store by using the id. I will try by modifying the computed property to get the desired product when the page is opened

Comment: You need another computed property for getting by ID.

Comment: I'll edit for getting by ID too.

Comment: Yes, I've solved it with a solution similar to the suggested. Thank you for the help

Comment: Could you be so kind as to mark my answer as the answer then please if it helped you solved the problem?

Comment: yes sir. Just a little doubt. If I need to dispatch an action that will manage a POST request, how I will pass a payload to the action?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `updateProductsData` mutation use `state.products = [...products]` to add your loaded products to your state

Check https://www.vuemastery.com/courses/vuex-fundamentals/vuex4-intro-to-vuex for a short intro to Vuex

Comment: In the original post, he's not currently making use of the store state, instead opting to get the data directly from the store action itself.

Comment: Well, i did see the comment inside his mutation and thought this might be the right way to do it (as vuex suggested it). A Component triggers an Action, an Action triggers a Mutation, a Mutation is setting the state, the Getter is getting the State and providing it to the Component.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to
the doc of Vuex about the use of actions and mutations https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html . It's detailed...

As Vuex suggests, you should put async operations in actions (like fetching data from the server in your example). Then you should commit a "mutation" to  use the fetched data to set your state like the code given below

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'

export default createStore({
  state: {
    products: []
  },
  mutations: {
    updateProductsData(state, products){
      // here set your state
      state.products = products
    }
  },
  actions: {
    fetchProducts({commit}){
      const baseURL = 'https://www.example.com/app/index.php/wp-json/shop/v1/products';
      let productsData = [];
      axios.get(baseURL).then( response => {
        response.data.forEach( el => {    
          console.log(el);
          let details = {
            id: el.id,
            slug: el.slug,
            name: el.name,
            price: el.price,
            description: el.description,
            short_description: el.short_description
          }
          productsData.push(details);
        });
        store.commit('updateProductsData', productsData);
      }).catch( e => console.log(e) );
    }
  }
})
```

If you want to use the state in your components, you can put it in computed attribute.

```
export default {
  name: 'Home',
  data(){
    return {
      loaded: false,
    }
  },
  computed:{
    // map this.offers to store.state.products
    offers(){
      return this.$store.state.products
    }
  },
  created(){

  }, 
  mounted(){
    // dispatch 'fetchProducts' to fetch data
    this.$store.dispatch('fetchProducts')
  },
}
```

Comment: if I need to access a state inside a vuex action I will need a getter right?

Comment: @BrP If you just want to access the state, you can inject `state` into parameters like `someAction({state, commit})` and simply use it in your actions.If you want to use getters in your action, just inject it like `someAction({state, commit, getters})`